# Change color of input text, not output

Tags: bash, centos, terminal, colors

I need to capture screenshots of the terminal where the typed commands visually "stand out" from the rest. Right now I'm using this to make my typed commands "red":

```
PS1='\[\e[0;31m\]\u\[\e[m\] \[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[m\] \[\e[0;34m\]\$ \[\e[m\]\[\e[0;31m\]'
```

The problem is: everything after the prompt is red, not only my typed text

[image: red linux output]

How can I fix this?

I'm using bash (CentOS 7).

Comment: I can't answer the question, but if you're willing to change shells [fish](http://fishshell.com/)  can do this.

Comment: You can pick up colors from http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes

Answer (score 6):

You can use a trap to achieve this:
`trap 'echo -ne "\e[0m"' DEBUG`

According to bash's man: a trap on `DEBUG` executes

> before every simple command,  for command,  case  command, select command, every arithmetic for command, and before the first command executes in a shell function

So every time you execute the command, the shell will insert `\e[0m` disabling the previous color code. Only to have it re-set via the prompt, once the command has executed.

I found the admitedly hackish trick here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#Different_colors_for_text_entry_and_console_output

Comment: Sorry, sorry, sorry! I forgot about this :-( Anyway: it ain't working on Ubuntu 16.04. See https://s9.postimg.org/jfnainjjj/Screenshot_from_2018-01-05_16-07-20.png What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So this one actually does work for me but I have an issue where if I type something out then use either CTRL-U or CTRL-W the entire line gets the background color styling instead of just the text at the prompt (which should be none at that point).

Comment: Otherwise this seems pretty close to a "good enough" solution. I just can't have my terminal's colors flail around like that since I use those shortcuts often.

Answer (score -1):

```
PS1='\[\e[0;31m\]\u\[\e[m\] \[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[m\] \[\e[0;34m\]\$ \[\e[m\]\[\e[1;31m\]'
```

You can fix this by changing the output colour, below is an example for the same.

```
PS1='\[\e[0;31m\]\u\[\e[m\] \[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[m\] \[\e[0;34m\]\$ \[\e[m\]\[\e[1;32m\]'
```

The above command displays the below output in green

Comment: No, this only changes the colors of the prompt but leaves the command line and the output from programs in the same color.

Comment: PS1 is the prompt, what the question is asking is the input text.  It's completely different.